# How much responsibility should the Model have in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

First off, I apologize if this question has already been asked and answered somewhere else? I've read many questions and answers on here regarding MVC, but not quite like this (yet).

My question is, how much should the Model in MVC, know? In almost every tutorial or MVC sample I've came across, the Page's Title and Description are set in a ViewBag, and then the layout reads from it, and sets it on the page.

To me, that seems a bit, not right. I would think that the a Model for that Controller and View, should have a Title property. To do this, I would have a BasePageModel with the Title, Description, and a Meta Collection. The controller would set each one, and then the _layout would have a @model BasePageModel and then set them on the page.

Is this "wrong" to do it this way (even though it does work), since the Model now kind of knows about the View/layout? Or is this more of a ViewModel than a Model?

Thanks

Comment: A data model should not have properties specific to the view, instead you should use view models (each view model could inherit from (say) ViewModelBase which has the properties for Title etc. to avoid use of `ViewBag`)

Comment: Another approach is to have a standard superclass for `ViewData` (`BaseViewData<TViewModel> : ViewDataDictionary<TViewModel>`, this approach works for me (and avoids using `ViewBag` entirely) but involves some plumbing later on. Whenever I define a view-model for a page I create a new `BaseViewData`-derived class as well, so the two are hand-in-hand related. The ViewModel only ever stores data the client browser will return to the server, and the ViewData only ever stores "one-way" data from the server to the client.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bit too broad and also a bit too opinionated for this format.  The MVC pattern is a suggested method for structuring code, it's not a law.  Many frameworks which are based around MVC have their own conventions which deviate slightly, but still stay true to the core suggestions, for the most part....

Comment: @StephenMuecke I agree that the data model (in my case EF) shouldn't know about the page, unless it's for something like a BlogPost, which has properties of Title and Description.

So then, for a BlogPost (EF data model) which has those two properties, how should they be passed to the View? Is it wrong to have a new BlogPostModel model in the MVC project (data models are in their own project), that has a Title property that the View reads from? Or, would doing so make it a "ViewModel"?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it belongs in a ViewModel. I think the slightly confusing part about your example is that you need to distinguish between the *blog* title and the *page* title.

You would typically have a generic ViewModelBase for all your pages that have title and description properties, which would be populated manually when you materialize the ViewModel. In the case of the Blog post you would populate The ViewModel from the BlogPost data model.

"MVC" as a design pattern doesn't account for proper layering of concerns. In it's purest form you either get logic in the controller or the model which is messy and sometimes hard to test.

Every dev shop has a slightly different way structure their projects for easy maintainability, everyones got an opinion (there's not right answer except whatevers easiest to maintain) But as an example, our apps layers are typically structured as

- Data Model (EF, only visible to queries, idealogically the "repository")
- Queries (context specific Model materialization - don't "include" what you don't need)
- Services (Collect data from external sources and aggregate)
- ViewModels (Only pass data that's required in the necessary format. if it looks simple, use automapper)